# Understanding the textual apparatus in Hebrews 13:9

Tags: textual-criticism, hebrews

How can the first and second variants both be suported by K and L?

> ⸀ περιφερεσθε K L |
>   ⸁ περιπατησαντες ℵ<sup>2</sup> C D<sup>2</sup> K L P Ψ 0243. 33. 81. 104. 365. 630. 1175. 1241. 1505. 1739. 1881
>   ¦ txt 46 ℵ<sup>✱</sup> A D<sup>✱</sup> co

<sup>(NA-28 apparatus; txt = περιπατοῦντες)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, they are not variants for the same particular word in Heb. 13:9. Rather, each one is a variant of a different word.

The Greek text of the [Nestle-Aland 28th edition of Heb. 13:9](https://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibelstelle/hebrews%2013%3A9/bibel/text/lesen/ch/f7505a31b3869e23630081cc9b3656f2/) reads:

> Διδαχαῖς ποικίλαις καὶ ξέναις μὴ **παραφέρεσθε**· καλὸν γὰρ χάριτι βεβαιοῦσθαι τὴν καρδίαν, οὐ βρώμασιν ἐν οἷς οὐκ ὠφελήθησαν οἱ **περιπατοῦντες**.

Thus, περιφερεσθε (περιφέρεσθε) is a variant of παραφέρεσθε (the first, bold-faced word), while περιπατησαντες (περιπατήσαντες) is a variant of περιπατοῦντες (the second, bold-faced word).

Coincidentally, the Greek text of the Textus Receptus (1550) reads,

> διδαχαῖς ποικίλαις καὶ ξέναις μὴ **περιφέρεσθε** καλὸν γὰρ χάριτι βεβαιοῦσθαι τὴν καρδίαν οὐ βρώμασιν ἐν οἷς οὐκ ὠφελήθησαν οἱ **περιπατήσαντες**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I feel silly for not realising that. At least I am unlikely to make the same mistake again.